# Null Pointer Exception because of Graphic Card?

Tags: c++, wpf, graphics

I need some unbiased views from experts. I bought BobCAD a couple months ago. It did run fine while evaluating and also after installation. Now, after some use it starts crashing with multiple "null Pointer" exceptions on closing the simulation mode.

Tech support is telling me that it is the graphic card that behaves (I quote:) "unpredictable". They say an integrated graphic card is only good for word and internet browsing.

However BobCad once run fine, I can perfectly play games, use CAD or other applications on my computer without crashing it. This leads me to having a hard time to believe this. BobCad does not use a lot of resources contrary to what they claim. There is no lagging or signs of useng my computer at the limit of what it is capable of.

From what I know you do not program the graphic card directly anymore - and certainly not in a CAM application, so those problems with graphic cards should be gone.

From what I see BobCad is a WPF application presumably written in C++

Please tell me, are they right? Is my suspicion of them not being very competent wrong?
Help me out with your experiences.

Best Regards

Leo

Comment: So, this is probably not really a good question for SO, but I would agree that it's not very likely that it's the graphics card that in and of itself is causing this sort of crashes. You'd have to debug the actual problem to be certain tho'.

Comment: Integrated graphics lag dedicated cards by about 5 years. Since BobCAD Tech Support lags reality by about a decade, I wouldn't say it matters.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, is it? -1 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A expensive dedicated graphic card is usually better than an integrated,
but that doesn´t means that integrated ones can´t do any real work.

Gc´s are directly programmed, even today (usage is even rising).
But, probably not in a WPF application...

Anyway, that all is no excuse for Nullpointerexceptions delivered to the user.
That´s simply a programming error, doesnt´t matter what your Gc is capable of.
If the program says "The Gc is too weak" it´s one thing, but crashing is inacceptable.

(And, incomptent support people are nothing unusual, sadly.)